# How to add image url and description to Magento 2 Rest API “rest/V1/categories”?

Tags: magento2, rest-api

in magento 2.1:

Categories Rest api "rest/V1/categories" returns data as follows

```
 {       
"id": 41,
          "parent_id": 3,
          "name": "Bakery",
          "is_active": true,
          "position": 4,
          "level": 2,
          "product_count": 0,
    "children_data": [],
}
```

how to modify it to return the category image and description ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add an image to the category under **Content** section of it, you'd get the image details under **custom_attributes** of your response.

[image: Magento CMS]

Here's my response for a particular category id `rest/V1/categories/:id`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

V1/categories/list?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=parent_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=2

**custom_attributes** in get image path
[image]